# Hibernate Annotations generating query that produces SQLGrammarException

Tags: hibernate, exception, annotations

Still duking it out with Hibernate...

I'm using Hibernate-Annotations instead of hbm.xml files for my beans, but I'm currently running into a problem where the SQL that Hibernate is generating references nonexistent database columns.

For instance, here is the code:

```
Query q = session.createQuery("FROM Status ORDER BY post_date DESC");
```

(it is retrieving a list of `Status` objects, ordered from most recent to least recent, and each `Status` object contains its own list of `Comment` objects...yes, think Facebook posts)

And here is the query it generates:

```
Hibernate: select status0_.pid as pid1_, status0_.content as content1_, status0_.owner_uid as owner5_1_, status0_.parent_pid as parent6_1_, status0_.post_date as post4_1_, status0_.type as type1_ from POSTS status0_ order by post_date DESC limit ?
```

The problem is, within that query, it references `status0_.owner_uid` and `status0_.parent_pid`, but those fields do not exist in the database. When I change the query manually to use `status0_.owner` and `status0_.parent`, respectively, and feed it to MySQL, it works perfectly.

There are four classes involved.

A `User`, which has no concept of anything else in the system (relevant fields below):

```
@Entity
@Embeddable
@Table(name="USERS")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="uid")
    private Integer uid;

...
}
```

A `Post`, an abstract superclass for `Comment` and `Status` that are stored in the same table and differentiated via a column `type` (relevant fields below):

```
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(
    name="type", 
    discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING
) 
@MappedSuperclass
@Entity
@Embeddable
@Table(name="POSTS")
public abstract class Post {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="pid")
    private Integer pid;

    @ManyToOne
    @Embedded
    private Post parent;

    @ManyToOne
    @Embedded
    private User owner;

    @Column(name="post_date")
    private Timestamp postDate;

    @Column(name="content")
    private String content;

    @Column(name="type", updatable=false)
    private String type;
    ...
}
```

A `Status` class, subclassing `Post`; sets `parent` to null and also contains a list of `Comment`s (relevant fields below):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="POSTS")
@DiscriminatorValue("status")
public class Status extends Post {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent")
    @OrderBy("postDate asc")
    private List<Comment> children; 
    ...
}
```

A `Comment` class, subclassing `Post`; has a non-null `parent` (entire class posted below):

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("comment")
@Table(name="shannonq_posts")
public class Comment extends Post {
    // this class is literally empty
}
```

In summary: I have no idea why Hibernate is appending the embedded class' IDs into the query, resulting in a non-existent column. Ideally I would have liked to have added the `@Column(name="parent")` annotation to these fields, but it seems that Hibernate doesn't allow this particular annotation to fields labeled with `@ManyToOne`.

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

**Edit**: FYI, if I manually change the columns in my database to match what Hibernate is generating, I get another error: `Cannot instantiate abstract class or interface: Post`. Obviously my configuration is incorrect. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate's default naming strategy for ManyToOne associations takes your field name and appends PK column of the associated table using underscore.

Thus for Post (superclass of Status) you get `owner_uid` and `parent_pid` as column names because `uid` and `pid` are respective PK column names.

You can override this by using @JoinColumn annotation:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "parent")
private Post parent;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "owner")
private User owner;
```

or by implementing your own NamingStrategy (Hibernate-specific and not recommended for beginners :-) )

On a side note, @Embedded signifies that you want to map given entity as component (basically, part of this same table). Putting @ManyToOne and @Embedded on the same property is (or should be) illegal.

Comment: I should just start messaging you when I have a Hibernate question :) Problem fixed! Thank you again!

Comment: No worries, that's why I hang out in the Hibernate tag :-)